# CSS error report from Wordpress describing filter error

Tags: css, wordpress, filter

```
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
```

gave this error

```
error Expected (<filter-function-list> | none) but found 'alpha(opacity=50)'.
```

Any idea why?

Comment: In the examples of w3schools there's a comment regarding browsers: /* For IE8 and earlier */ Have you tried different ones?

Comment: If changing the browser doesn't solve this, maybe the problem is in another part of the file and not this concrete line..